# stash/unstash isn't working for linux link

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am building llvm project in linux and windows. After the build is finished I am trying to stash the next files in linux:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jenkins sdt        9 Jan 23 21:10 clang -> clang-4.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jenkins sdt        5 Jan 23 21:10 clang++ -> clang
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins sdt 67185165 Jan 23 21:09 clang-4.0
```

with the next command

```
    stash includes: 'bin/clang, bin/clang++, bin/clang, bin/clang-4.0', name: 'clang_linux'
```

and although the log says that 3 files stashed

```
[linux_builder] Stashed 3 file(s)
```

when doing unstash in windows node(in order to zip both windows and linux) I get only one file: bin/clang-4.0 but not the rest. why ?

Comment: We are seeing the same thing; unstashing on Linux preserves the links, unstashing on Windows does not. This used to work for us with Jenkins 2.84, but when we upgrade from that to 2.104 it stopped working. We are still investigating the cause or possible solutions.